# Dwr and script session invalidation

Tags: dwr

We are using reverse ajax with polling in our DWR 2.0.6 based application. The problem is that when we move away from a page where reverse ajax was set to true, we want that ScriptSession to be invalidated. It does not happen by default. 
In the docs for DWR 3.0 it is mentioned that we can call dwr.engine.setNotifyServerOnPageUnload(true); in our js file

But this is not available in 2.0.6.
Any ideas suggestions etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You could write this manually, using an "onbeforeunload" handler.